# LINQ: DataContext Life and System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, timeout

i seem to be getting a lot of this in my Linq 2 SQL

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

There is really no reason for it, its a simple query that returns 1 record.

I was thinking about opening my datacontext within a Using statement on each method that needs it, i currently am using a private module level variable to open the datacontext..

Is this recommended?

I don't see why it would be timing out, i can only think that i have too many data contexts around....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datacontext is designed to be opened when you use it, and then thrown away.  For example:

```
using (var dc = new MyDataContext())
    dc.sp_DailyJob();
```

Right after the `using` block, the datacontext is released back to the connection pool.

Now, if you cache a DataContext in a local module, it might go unused for a while.  Then SQL Server will eventually close your connection because it's idle for too long.  The next call generates the `Timeout expired` message.

I'd remove the caching of the DataContext, and keep create a new DataContext for every call or query you run.  Dispose them as soon as you can.  There's no performance overhead in that, because the connections are cached by a highly optimized connection pool.

Comment: Thanks Andomar, just what i was looking for, this is what i expected.. but was unsure .. thanks for confirming..

Answer (score 2):

There is a good article [here](http://dotnetlog.com/archive/2008/03/18/best-practice-and-effective-way-of-using-datacontext-in-linq.aspx) *(Best practice and effective way of using DataContext in Linq to SQL*) about Linq 2 SQL data context best practices... Might be worth a read :)